# Мужчина, который прядет

Tags: грамотная-речь

Здравствуйте! Всех с наступающим!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, а как назвать мужчину, который прядет шерсть? Женщина — пряха, а мужчина? Мне приходит на ум только "прядильщик".
Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Можно сказать прядильщик, а можно шерстопряд. Раньше слово употреблялось.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно сказать прядильщик.

Comment: Правильно не заниматься прядением шерсти, если в языке для этого даже слова подходящего нет.

Comment: Согласна. Правда, однажды мужчины захотели доить коров...и появились дояры.

Comment: Прядильщик-прядильщица (наверное, после автоматизации процесса). А для пряхи пары нет. Ну не пряли мужики на Руси!

Answer (score 1):

Я бы о мужчине тоже сказал **пряха**. Как и, например, **няня**: "Я был его нянькой". Такие слова как-то тянутся к общему роду.